# Rust decimal to roman numeral kata

Tags: rust, roman-numerals

I just wrote this decimal to Roman numeral converter, inspired by [Kevlin Henney's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_M4o0ExLQCs) talk "Get Kata".

I have been reading the Rust docs little by little and this is one of my first attempts at some code.

I'd like to get feedback on style, general rust idioms and how I could have implemented **this** algorithm in a more succinct manner.

Code also available [here](https://github.com/jamespeterschinner/kata).

```
use std::env;
use std::io;
use std::io::BufWriter;
use std::io::Write;

static BASE10_NUMERALS: [&str; 7] = ["I", "X", "C", "M", "X̄", "C̄", "M̄"];

static CENTRE_NUMERALS: [&str; 6] = ["V", "L", "D", "V̄", "L̄", "D̄"];

struct Bases {
    base: usize
}


impl Iterator for Bases {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        self.base = self.base - 1;
        Some(self.base)
    }
}

fn iter_bases(largest_base: usize) -> Bases {
    Bases { base: largest_base }
}


fn encode((decimal_number, base, ): (char, usize, )) -> String {
    let digit = decimal_number.to_digit(10).unwrap();
    let max_base = CENTRE_NUMERALS.len();

    if base >= max_base {
        BASE10_NUMERALS[BASE10_NUMERALS.len() - 1]
            //This pow function is the main limiter for decimal size
            .repeat((10_u32.pow((base - max_base) as u32) * digit) as usize)
    } else {
        if digit == 9 {
            format!("{}{}"
                    , if base == 3 { "Ī"} else { BASE10_NUMERALS[base] }
                    , BASE10_NUMERALS[base + 1]
            )
        } else if digit >= 5 {
            format!("{}{}", CENTRE_NUMERALS[
                base], BASE10_NUMERALS[base]
                        .repeat((digit - 5) as usize))
        } else if digit == 4 {
            format!("{}{}", BASE10_NUMERALS[base], CENTRE_NUMERALS[base])
        } else {
            // Less than 4
            BASE10_NUMERALS[base].repeat(digit as usize)
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(io::stdout());
    let input = &args[1];
    for roman_numeral in input
        .chars()
        .zip(iter_bases(input.len()))
        .map(encode) {
        writer.write(roman_numeral.as_bytes())
            .expect("Unable to write to stdout");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `cargo fmt` and `cargo clippy`

Use `cargo fmt` to format your code according to the official Rust
Style Guide.

Clippy's suggestions:

- collapse `else { if .. }` into `else if ..`;
- change `self.base = self.base - 1` to `self.base -= 1`;
- use `write_all` instead of `write` when writing a slice of bytes,
  since the latter only makes one writing attempt:

  > `io::Write::write(_vectored)` and `io::Read::read(_vectored)` are
  > not guaranteed to process the entire buffer. They return how many
  > bytes were processed, which might be smaller than a given buffer’s
  > length. If you don’t need to deal with partial-write/read, use
  > `write_all`/`read_exact` instead.  ([source](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#unused_io_amount))

## The interface

Instead of passing in a tuple, it is preferable to pass separate
parameters:

```
fn encode(decimal_number: char, base: usize) -> String {
    // ...
}
```

Now, we notice that the interface is fairly curious.  A better
self-explanatory interface might simply be:

```
fn to_roman(number: u32) -> String {
    // ...
}
```

which can be coded to encapsulate calls to `encode` while avoiding
repetitive allocation.

## Grouping `use` declarations

It's common to group `use` declarations together:

```
use std::{
    env,
    io::{self, BufWriter, Write},
};
```

## The `Bases` utility

`Bases` is not necessary — you can use `(0..n).rev()` to iterate
from `n - 1` to `0`.

Comment: Thanks! All great points, I really should have known about `(0..n).rev()`.